# Android GPS update location

Tags: java, android, gps, location

I am making simple application which based on phone's location. I am using [this code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) for GPS location. In the `main()` function I am requesting the GPS location and then I am working with it. (I am calculating the sunrise and sunset)

I can get the location, but when I start the application I get the `LastKnown` location. So, if I want real "new one" location I must wait for GPS lock on and then restart the application.

So, my question is: How can I get a "fresh" location?

Ok. I have an idea.

Can I call MainActivity refresh from another class?

in GPS class I have this

```
private final Context mContext;

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
}
```

But this doesn't work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) is the overview of location services in Android. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) is the `LocationManager` class at the heart of location services in Android.

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) is an Android developer tutorial on "Location Strategies". [Here](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2008-12-15-n14.html) is another tutorial that might be usable.

Also, you cannot just ask Android for your current position, since GPS may take quite some time to get a fix. Instead, you need to request location updates and use the first update you get, or similar patterns.

Comment: I have all calculation in one function. So how can I wait until GPS get a fix and send me location update? Because without wait it will calculate without it.

Comment: Read the links in my answer.

Comment: Can you help me with the code of that please? I can't get it.